# How can I save and edit with ajax php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I need to make a crud to save and edit with ajax php and mysql, but I don't know too much of ajax.

I'm having trouble saving and editing a new record in the database.

Here are my codes to make it easier to understand.

I am grateful for your help.

**index.php**

```
<style>
body{width:40%;}
.message-box{margin-bottom:20px;border-top:#F0F0F0 2px solid;background:#FAF8F8;padding:10px;}
.btnEditAction{background-color:#45619D;border:0;padding:2px 10px;color:#FFF;}
.btnSaveAction{background-color:#2FC332;border:0;padding:2px 10px;color:#FFF; position: relative; top: -19px; z-index: 10;}
.btnsave{background-color:#2FC332;border:0;padding:2px 10px;color:#FFF; position: relative; top: -19px; z-index: 10;}
.salvar2{display: none !important;}
</style>

<?php
    require_once("dbcontroller.php");
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    $comments = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM comment");
?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

function showEditBox(editobj,id) {
    $('.valor').show();
    $('.salvar').addClass('salvar2');
    $('#frmAdd').show();
    $(editobj).prop('disabled','true');
    var currentMessage = $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html();
    var editMarkUp = '<button name="ok" class="btnSaveAction" onClick="callCrudAction(\'edit\','+id+')">Save</button><textarea class="valor2" rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_'+id+'">'+currentMessage+'</textarea>';
    $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html(editMarkUp);
    $('.btnSaveAction').show();
}

function callCrudAction(action,id) {
     $("#loaderIcon").show();
     var queryString;
     switch(action) {
         case "edit":
        queryString = 'action='+action+'&message_id='+ id + '&txtmessage='+ $("#txtmessage_"+id).val();
    break;
    case "save":
        queryString = 'action='+action+'&message_id='+ id + '&txtmessage='+ $("#txtmessage_"+id).val();
    break;
}    
jQuery.ajax({
url: "crud_action.php",
data:queryString,
type: "POST",
success:function(data){
    switch(action) {
        case "edit":
            $('.valor').hide();
            $('.salvar').addClass('salvar2');
            $('.btnEditAction').show();
            $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html(data);
            $('#frmAdd').show();
            $("#message_"+id+" .btnEditAction").prop('disabled','');
        break;

        case "save":
            $('.valor').hide();
            $('.salvar').addClass('salvar2');
            $('.btnEditAction').show();
            $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html(data);
            $('#frmAdd').show();
            $("#message_"+id+" .btnEditAction").prop('disabled','');
        break;
    }
    $("#txtmessage").val('');
    $("#loaderIcon").hide();
},
error:function (){}
});
}
</script>

<div class="form_style">
<div id="comment-list-box">
<?php
    if(!empty($comments)) {
    foreach($comments as $k=>$v) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var indice = "<?php echo $comments[$k]["id"];?>";
</script>

<div class="message-box" id="message_<?php echo $comments[$k]["id"];?>">
<div>
<?php if($v['message'] != "") { ?>
<button class="btnEditAction" name="edit" onClick="showEditBox(this,<?php echo $comments[$k]["id"]; ?>)">Edit</button>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($v['message'] == "") { ?>
     <button style="display: none" class="btnEditAction" name="edit" onClick="showEditBox(this,<?php echo $comments[$k]["id"]; ?>)">Edit</button>
     <button name="ok" class="btnSaveAction salvar" onClick="callCrudAction('save','indice')">Save</button><textarea class="valor" rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_'<?php echo $comments[$k]["id"]; ?>'"></textarea>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="message-content"><?php echo $comments[$k]["message"]; ?></div>
</div>
<?php
}
} ?>
</div>

<img src="LoaderIcon.gif" id="loaderIcon" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

**dbcontroller.php**

```
<?php
class DBController {
private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "root";
private $password = "";
private $database = "database";

function __construct() {
    $conn = $this->connectDB();
    if(!empty($conn)) {
        $this->selectDB($conn);
    }
}

function connectDB() {
    $conn = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
    return $conn;
}

function selectDB($conn) {
    mysql_select_db($this->database,$conn);
}

function runQuery($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }       
    if(!empty($resultset))
        return $resultset;
}

function numRows($query) {
    $result  = mysql_query($query);
    $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
    return $rowcount;   
}
}
?>
```

**crud_action.php**

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();

$action = $_POST["action"];
if(!empty($action)) {
switch($action) {           
    case "edit":
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE comment set message = '".$_POST["txtmessage"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["message_id"]);
        if($result){
              echo $_POST["txtmessage"];
        }
        break;

    case "save":
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE comment set message = '".$_POST["txtmessage"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["message_id"]);
        if($result){
              echo $_POST["txtmessage"];
        }
        break;          
    }
}
?>
```

**database.sql**

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment` (
    `id` int(100) NOT NULL,
    `message` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `comment` (`id`, `message`) VALUES
(1, '3'),
(2, '2'),
(4, ''),
(5, '');

ALTER TABLE `comment`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually works pretty well as is. You were just missing an insert function to call in `crud_action.php`. I created a stored procedure for this so that it would be parameterized and return the new ID.

Also I used an auto-incrementing primary key in your DDL.

This is at least working, but you should still very much look into using the [mysqli functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and **SANITIZE** your inputs - I'll leave that one to you and google as there are plenty of examples.

Then you needed a blank "new" textarea for new comments, and to finish implementing the ajax call for that.

The buggy behavior it currently exudes is because the way you handle empty values. To clean it up, you just need to get rid of the clunky redundant blank textarea for empty valued columns.

### index.php

```
<style>
body{width:40%;}
.message-box{margin-bottom:20px;border-top:#F0F0F0 2px solid;background:#FAF8F8;padding:10px;}
.btnEditAction{background-color:#45619D;border:0;padding:2px 10px;color:#FFF;}
.btnSaveAction{background-color:#2FC332;border:0;padding:2px 10px;color:#FFF; position: relative; top: -19px; z-index: 10;}
.btnsave{background-color:#2FC332;border:0;padding:2px 10px;color:#FFF; position: relative; top: -19px; z-index: 10;}
.salvar2{display: none !important;}
</style>

<?php
    require_once("dbcontroller.php");
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    $comments = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM comment");
?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

function showEditBox(editobj,id) {
    $('.valor').show();
    $('.salvar').addClass('salvar2');
    $('#frmAdd').show();
    $(editobj).prop('disabled','true');
    var currentMessage = $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html();
    var editMarkUp = '<button name="ok" class="btnSaveAction" onClick="callCrudAction(\'edit\','+id+')">Save</button><textarea class="valor2" rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_'+id+'">'+currentMessage+'</textarea>';
    $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html(editMarkUp);
    $('.btnSaveAction').show();
}

function callCrudAction(action,id) {
     $("#loaderIcon").show();
     var queryString;
     switch(action) {
         case "edit":
        queryString = 'action='+action+'&message_id='+ id + '&txtmessage='+ $("#txtmessage_"+id).val();
    break;
    case "save":
        queryString = 'action='+action+'&message_id='+ id + '&txtmessage='+ $("#txtmessage_"+id).val();
    break;
}    
jQuery.ajax({
url: "crud_action.php",
data:queryString,
type: "POST",
success:function(data){
    switch(action) {
        case "edit":
            $('.valor').hide();
            $('.salvar').addClass('salvar2');
            $('.btnEditAction').show();
            $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html(data);
            $('#frmAdd').show();
            $("#message_"+id+" .btnEditAction").prop('disabled','');
        break;

        case "save":
            $('.valor').hide();
            $('.salvar').addClass('salvar2');
            $('.btnEditAction').show();
            $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html(data);
            $('#frmAdd').show();
            $("#message_"+id+" .btnEditAction").prop('disabled','');
        break;
    }
    $("#txtmessage").val('');
    $("#loaderIcon").hide();
},
error:function (){}
});
}

function create_comment(){
  var payload = "action=save&txtmessage=" + $("#newComment").val();
  console.log(payload);
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "crud_action.php",
    data: payload,
    success: function(result_id){
      console.log(result_id);
      // clone the template
      var new_msg_box = $("#msgBoxTemplate").clone();
      // set the new ID
      new_msg_box.attr("id","message_"+result_id);
      // set the edit ajax ID
      new_msg_box.find("button").attr("onClick","showEditBox(this,"+result_id+")");
      // set the message content
      new_msg_box.children(".message-content").text($("#newComment").val());
      // clear the new message textarea
      $("#newComment").val("");
      // show the new message
      $("#comment-list-box").append(new_msg_box);
      new_msg_box.show();
    }
  });
}

</script>

<div class="form_style">
  <div id="comment-list-box">
  <?php
  if(!empty($comments)) {
    foreach($comments as $k=>$v) { ?>

      <div class="message-box" id="message_<?php echo $comments[$k]["id"];?>">
        <div>
          <button class="btnEditAction" name="edit" onClick="showEditBox(this,<?php echo $comments[$k]["id"]; ?>)">Edit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="message-content"><?php echo $comments[$k]["message"]; ?></div>
      </div>

    <?php } // END foreach
  } // END if(!empty($comments)) ?>
  </div>

<textarea class="valor2" rows="5" cols="80" id="newComment"></textarea>
<button name="ok" class="btnSaveAction" onClick="create_comment()">Create New</button>
</div>

<!-- template for cloning -->
<div class="message-box" id='msgBoxTemplate' style='display:none'>
  <div>
    <button class="btnEditAction" name="edit">Edit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="message-content"></div>
</div>
```

### crud_action.php

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$action = $_POST["action"];
if(!empty($action)) {
switch($action) {           
    case "edit":
        // SANITIZE HERE
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE comment set message = '".$_POST["txtmessage"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["message_id"]);
        if($result){
              echo $_POST["txtmessage"];
        }
        break;

    case "save":
        // SANITIZE HERE
        $result = mysql_query("CALL create_comment('".$_POST["txtmessage"]."')");
        if($result){
              $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
              echo $row["new_id"];
        }
        break;          
    }
}
?>
```

### database.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comment`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `message` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `comment` (`message`) VALUES
('first comment'),
('2nd comment'),
('3rd comment'),
('4th comment');

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS create_comment;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE create_comment( 
  p_message VARCHAR(100)
)
this_procedure:BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `comment` (`message`)
  VALUES (p_message);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS 'new_id';
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hello
Thank you very much.
It was exactly what I needed, I can now give sequence.
Grateful!